Getting 403 error of Google Cloud API only inside Docker
A couple of days ago my Google Cloud APIs started to return 403 error.
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 403 (Forbidden); transport: received unexpected content-type "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

I use Logging API and Vertex API with official Go clients.
The wired part is when I run it without Docker on the same server it works fine. Also when I run it on other server in Docker it also works fine.
I don't know whats the problem in my current server.
I created minimal program to reproduce the bug:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "cloud.google.com/go/logging"
)

func main() {
    projectID := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_LOGGING_PROJECT_ID")
    logName := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_LOGGING_LOG_NAME")

    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := logging.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }

    logInfo := client.Logger(logName)

    err = logInfo.LogSync(ctx, logging.Entry{
        Payload: "This is a test log message",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to log message: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Logged message to Google Cloud Logging")

}


and with sh file works fine:
#!/bin/sh

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=google-credentials.json
export GOOGLE_LOGGING_PROJECT_ID=summ-435417
export GOOGLE_LOGGING_LOG_NAME=main
./gce_log_test

but in Docker not
version: "3.8"
services:
  gce-test:
    image: golang:alpine
    container_name: gce-test
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/app/google-credentials.json
      - GOOGLE_LOGGING_PROJECT_ID=summ-435417
      - GOOGLE_LOGGING_LOG_NAME=main
    volumes:
      - /home/summ/gce-test:/home/app
    working_dir: /home/app
    command: ["./gce_log_test"]


You mean "weird", but that's not a useful term here anyway. Please revise to correct your spelling and make your title a clear, specific question. See [ask].

It seems the issue with IPv6
error 403: Your client does not have permission to get URL in python google cloud module
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/General-Misc-Q-A/How-do-I-unblock-my-server-s-IP/m-p/649978

Yes, you need the keys in your container. Does it work now?

What keys do you mean? Google API? It’s not the case. The problem is Google is blocking ipv6 of Hetzner. And in container requests go via ipv6 but on host machine via ip4.

You have a L7 error because of L3 issue? Hard to believe...
